# How to compare 2 pairs of numbers?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to efficiently compare 2 pairs of numbers?

Is `[a, b] > [c, d]` equivalent to `a > c || a === c && b > d` in Javascript?

===========

Edit question: how does Javascript evaluate `[a, b] > [c, d]` expression?

Comment: No, in the first one, you are using a comparison operator to compare arrays which doesn't work in JavaScript.

Comment: What's wrong with your second code? Why do you think its not "efficient"?

Comment: `[a, b] > [c, d]` what is this is that like comparison? did you mean the comparison like this `a > =c && b >= d`

Comment: @rockstar: in the second code if `a` or `b` is returned result of a function, there is need to caching them by a new variable to avoid double calling same function

Comment: Are the 2 pairs of numbers really in an array ?

Comment: @transang: And why is storing them in a variable a problem? Do you think that creating arrays won't have its own overhead?

Comment: no. they are separated variables. And have long name. I just try finding more efficient way if possible

Comment: the reason why i came to this question is that when I try with browser `[1, 2] > [0, 3]` or `[3, 4] > [3,2]`, ..., they returned the  expected result. Thus, i think the first code in my question should work

Comment: @transang: It's converting them to strings, so the comparison becomes `"1,2" > "0,3"`. This does work as long as you always have single digit numbers. Try this: `[10, 2] > [2, 1]`. Suddenly it fails.

Comment: @rockstar: awesome. your comment should be my accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Is [a, b] > [c, d] equivalent to a > c || a === c && b > d in Javascript?"*

No, the correct results you're getting is because of the single digit numbers you're using. See below.

> *"how does Javascript evaluate [a, b] > [c, d] expression?"*

Because you're not comparing numbers, they two arrays get converted to strings. So substituting the numeric values for the variables, we may get this:

```
"1,2" > "0,3"
```

This does work as long as you always have single digit numbers.

Try this:

```
[10, 2] > [2, 1]
```

Suddenly it fails. This is because the lexical comparison of `"10,2"` and `"2,1"` places the second value at a greater position.

Comment: It seems that `"1,2" > "0,3" is indeed `true` and that they are not coerced to numbers (because `Number("1,2")` is `NaN`). Could you explain how this happens ?

Comment: They get converted to the strings shown, and the equality comparison operators are overloaded in JS to handle string comparison. So it's simply a lexical comparison of the string content, just like you'd expect from comparing `"foo" > "bar"; // true`

Comment: I get the alphabetical ordering, but it seems that `"19" > "2"` is `false` while `"20" > "2"` is `true`. What is going on ?

Comment: @Taurus: In an alphabetic comparison, it's a left-to-right comparison where you halt with a result as soon as you find inequality. So in `"19 > "2"`, the `"1"` is less than the `"2"`, so it can stop and return `false`.

Comment: ...just like `"apple" > "b"` is `false`. There's more *data* with `"apple"`, but it's still lexically lower than a single `"b"`.

Comment: So the second comparison must be `"20" > "2"` after `"2" > "2"` does not result in an inequality ? Needless to say, I have a deja vu feeling here, I don't know. Thanks for keeping up though, +1.

Comment: @Taurus: The `"20" > "2"` is because both of the `2` being equal, it then moves to the next character. So it's `"0" > [[no value]]`. Since there's no value to compare on the right, the `"0"` is considered greater. Just like an alphabetic comparison of `"aa"` is greater than `"a"`, like how `"aardvark"` comes after `"a"` in the dictionary. so `"aardvark" > "a"`

Comment: Could you provide some links ? If not, I recommend adding it to your answer. It would be much greater a service to have all this information as one big paragraph instead of it being scattered across multiple comments.

Comment: I am currently reading You Don't Know JS: types & grammar, it seems that I was some 20 pages from the part where the book explains the stuff that is in play here. [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md) is a link to the chapter (jump to the "Abstract Relational Comparison" part) where he explains this. I really have to do something else right now or I would read it (and possibly edit some of its parts into your answer), I am adding it with the intention of facilitating what I recommended in the above comment.

Comment: @Taurus: You can read the spec details of the abstract relational comparison algorithm [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison). While the spec can be a bit daunting sometimes, it's useful to pursue. Click over to the `ToPrimitive` algorithm, which is invoked with the `number` hint. If you follow it through, you'll see at one point that an object will have its `.valueOf()` method called followed by its `.toString()`. Then back at the original algorithm, point 3 describes the  string comparison.

Comment: Quick demo showing the `.valueOf()` and `.toString()` being invoked: https://jsfiddle.net/ez47o1kz/

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the effort and service :)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a function for an arbitrary length.

```js
function isGreater(aa, b) {
    return aa.some((_, i, a) =>  a[i - 1] === b[i - 1] && a[i] > b[i]);
}

console.log(isGreater([1, 2], [3, 5]));
console.log(isGreater([3, 2], [3, 5]));
console.log(isGreater([3, 6], [3, 5]));
console.log(isGreater([4, 2], [3, 5]));
```

Comment: OP does not want to check if the sum of `arr1` is greater than `arr2`, he/she actually wants ` a > c || a === c && b > d`.

Comment: @Taurus, where do you see a sum? the calculation is for the indices.

Comment: ooops! the result of your function calls (the first 3) are situated in a way that misled me, you see: `3 < 8`, `5 < 8`, and `9 > 5` (I didn't care to look at the 4th one). Sorrryyy.

Answer (score 0):

**For your problem, you should use the solution you added in your question: `a > c || a === c && b > d`, and it is not inefficient at all.**

If you are repeating the same task multiple times, then go create a function for it:

```
function custom_comparison(a, b, c, d) {
return a > c || a === c && b > d;
}
```

**Edit**: the first part of my answer was clearly wrong, @rockStar's answer is the correct one in that regard, so I just deleted my explanation.

Comment: `[a, b] > [c, d]` does **not always** return `false`

Comment: It isn't `NaN > NaN`. They get converted to strings, which get compared.

Comment: @transang If the array's value of returns a number, or if the arrays contain only 1 element, it won't.

Comment: @rockstar The strings will get converted to numbers afterwards, which is why "var a = [1,2]; 
var b = [3,4];

a.toString = function() {
return "20"; 
};

b.toString = function() {
return "10"; 
};

console.log(a > b);" will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @Taurus: No they don't. Once converted to strings, they're compared as strings, lexically.

Comment: @rockstar how is "20" > "10" `true` ?

Comment: They're converted to numbers. But how do you get `"20"` from an array of two members?

Comment: @rockstar You don't, you get `NaN`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159301/discussion-between-taurus-and-rock-star).

Comment: @rockstar By the `"20" > "10"`, I am talking about the example I provided in my comment.

Comment: To be clear (and to correct myself because I had a couple things going on at the time), `"20" > "10"` does not get converted to numbers. They are compared lexically as strings. The reason you get `true` from that comparison is that both numerically and lexically, `20` is greater than `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a nested comparison such as on strings. You may simply do like;

```
[1,3].join() > [1,2].join() // <- true
```

or ugly but by coercing

```
[1,3]+"" > [1,2] // <- true
```